# Arctan:-Fibonacci series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\arctan\left({1\over \phi^{2n}}\right)=\arctan\left({1\over F_{2n+1}}\right)-
\arctan\left({1\over F_{2n+3}}\right)+\arctan\left({1\over F_{2n+5}}\right)-\cdots\tag1$$

$n\ge1$ and $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Where [$F_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is the Fibonacci Number

I am very curious to how does one go about to prove $(1)$

Comment: Small hint: formulas like these tend to involve addition formulas for $\arctan.$

Comment: However, is this even true? For $n=0$ it seems to be wrong.

Comment: The induction step would be $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{F_{2n+1}}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{\phi^{2n}}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{\phi^{2n+2}}\right)$$ but this isn't true for $n=1$, so there must be some mistake above.